# Setting Input Value with a Variable at set interval

Tags: setinterval

I have an HTML input text box and I am trying to use Javascript to display a live clock inside this text box (ie. use a script to update the current time every second, and insert this current time into the value=""

To do this, I have a javascript function startTime() running to grab the current time in 00:00:00 format. Then I'm using another function setInputValue() to make  the results of function startTime() as the "value" of the input text box

This works and displays the current time inside the text box, as expected.

Since this only displays the time that the scripts were loaded, I need a setInterval() to make it update every second. Unfortunately, adding var t = setInterval(startTime, 1000); does not do it. I've also tried setInterval(setInputValue, 1000); and that does not change the time each second, either.

I'm pasting my code here on this link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1B141Z87FCF

Edit to add: While there are probably easier methods than making the end result the value of an input text box, I am having to do it this way because this "live time" will be displayed as an overlay on a video stream. The only way I have access to editing the text of this video overlay is by changing the "value" of the text box. It all works to display the time, it's just not changing each second unless I manually refresh the script.

Thank you for any help you could provide.

Comment: Use this, setInterval(function() {
 setInputValue('textbox', startTime());
}, 1000);

Comment: @vermanil Thank you so much! That worked perfectly!